# How to remove side boxes from admin dashboard of wordpress

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I don't know whether they are called meta boxes or so.. But I need to remove one of the side boxes from the admin portion of wordpress.. And I can't find where the code for them is. I've attached a screenshot with this question.
[image]

Comment: Which box you want to remove might help...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need for any code. You see Screen options tab, at top of the page. Press it, and then tap checkboxes to show/hide any boxes. Image:

[image: Press here]

If yu want totally hide sideboard, press 1 on the radio buttons below checkboxes(column count).